# A relocating friend gave me their potted fig tree which is now thriving in my ground - but no flowers or fruit!

Tags: tree-care, figs

A relocating friend gave me their weak looking potted fig shrub tree in July. I planted it in semi shade as the weather was very hot - but in our yard it is absolutely thriving - seems very happy and has become nearly 4'X 4'. But it has borne no flowers or fruit till now.
A neighbor of mine planted a tiny fig tree in July and it has about twenty fruits on it!
I have an organic garden that is very well frequented by bees, birds and butterflies. I did put fruit fertilizer once a month.
Please help.
Pictures
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3QRd.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would assume your relocating friend did a number on the poor guy. Give it time, another year perhaps. If there is still no fruit then pull it out and toss it.

Comment: Plants tend to produce seed when they are running out of other options to survive. If your fig has gone from "weak looking" to growing strongly, don't expect if to produce much fruit till the growth slows down to normal. Pruning it correctly will encourage it to fruit, of course.

Comment: pictures please

Comment: The other unknown plant in the photo is competing with it, but the fig bush looks very healthy anyway.  You could cut back the other plant to allow for more light to the fig, but It probably just needs to mature a little.

Comment: There are two kinds of leaves on this fig tree. While it looks like another plant is competing - its the same tree -  its strange that this tree has two very distinct shaped leaves.

Comment: Figs can have two differently shaped types of leaves, especially when young.

Comment: Thank you. I will prune it back carefully to open and air the inner branches. Hopefully it will bear fruit next season. I'm also relieved that the reason it didn't bear any fruit this year was due to immaturity. I was worried this variety might only be an ornamental variety and incapable of bearing fruit.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only 4' in a season it may still be growing roots from the transplant shock. Figs are very vigorous growers ( in East TX) and require chain saw type pruning every year. I do not fertilize it directly but there are plantings 12 ft away that get some fertilizer. They need water in hot, dry weather. Is it possibly not a fig ?

Answer (score 1):

Figs require 3 to 4 years to produce a  crop after planting so don't trash it next year! LSU Purple is a rare exception.

If in full six hours direct sun, planted properly so crown not buried & up slightly (like on a pitchers mound to ensure good drainage), well watered the 1st year, fertilized by Feb or March, 4 inch layer of mulch out to the root canopy to protect its shallow roots & you'll get your figs in 2-3 years!

They fruit on new wood produced the previous year so be careful pruning.

If it was pot bound, did you loosen up the roots? And, dig hole 2-3 x's wider?

Top dress with compost to give it a boost.